# Rect extend middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, middleware

First of all, I'm coming for php background and I'm currently sort of building a middleware in react, the way I would do this would be something like:

```js
class Middleware extends React.Component {
  funcOne(data) {
    return data;
  }

  funcTwo(data) {
    return (
      <div>
        { data }
        <br />
        { this.funcThree('Third function') }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MyComponent extends Middleware {
  funcOne(data) {
    return `Rewrite of ${data}`;
  }

  funcThree(data) {
    return data;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.funcOne('First function') }
        { this.funcTwo('Second function') }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MySecondComponent extends Middleware {
  funcThree(data) {
    return data;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.funcOne('First function') }
        { this.funcTwo('Second function') }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <MyComponent />
    <hr />
    <MySecondComponent />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

However I can't really find any documentation on whether to do or not to do this.
So, is this wrong?
And if so, how should I do this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your updated code, just create a component for `funcTwo` and pass a prop to it:

```
function funcOne () {
  return 'First function';
}

function Two (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      Second function
      <br />
      { props.three }
    </div>
  );
}

//...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { funcOne() }
        <br />
        <Two three={this.funcThree()} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

---

I've never seen any use cases that must use inheritance in React. In your case, just create components or plain functions. Besides, a component can also be a plain function:

this can be a component:

```
function One (props) {
  return <h1>hello</h1>
}
```

You use it like this:

```
<One />
```

Or, if you just need strings, simply write functions:

```
function funcOne () {
  return 'First function';
}

function funcTwo () {
  return 'Second function';
}

// ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { funcOne() }
        <br />
        { funcTwo() }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Thus you don't need inheritance at all. In JavaScript, especially React, you should try to think in a more functional way. You will find that it's very powerful and flexible.

You can find an official documentation about component composition here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

I also recommend you to read this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: Hi, I did simplify my components a bit but I will need component-functions such as 'componentWillUnmount' aso in both the components and I would also like to use the "upper" component in other components

Comment: I'd definitely second this answer - I think in all the time I've been using React, I've *never* had to subclass a component (and as shown in the links to the docs, they actively recommend against doing it).

Comment: The component in question will be widely used through out the entire project and I don't really see how the Hoc lets you send functions back and forth the way I intended

Comment: I see where you're going with this but it looks really "wonky" as you would have to check if each props where set and then depending on which props where set you'd have to load different functions instead of having one function loaded and being updated depending on if the child-version exists or not. Another thing, I would like to call the "upper" component in 'componentWillMount' before render

Comment: Um.. I don't fully understand your question and use case. For the snippet in your question, this is the classic React way to achieve - using components and passing props down. If you want to reuse lifecycle hooks, you can use higher order components.

Comment: I have updated my question, what I want basically is a component that has a default behavior to do x with what I send into it but dependent on how I call it it acts different, I could make it a huge file where I check for every scenario but I wanna keep the file as small and clean as possible

Answer (score 0):

What you want to implement is commonly called a higher order component. [Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) is the detailed doc.

Comment: Will a higher order component have access to functions from the lower order component? (updated my original question)

Comment: No it won't, higher order components wrap components that have shared methods. So that you don't have to keep writing the same methods when implementing these lower order components. Which is something that you are trying to do, right?

Comment: I'm basically trying to create a "handler" for whatever data I send into it and then bad the chance to modify the handler if needed

Comment: I see. If I were you, I will use state management API like redux to handle the data before passing it to react.

Comment: this does not really apply to the way redux is intended to be used unless I miss something

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you do reuse in react world is by creating functions that take a component and return a new component with added functionality, wrapping it in a component that adds functionality to it.

This can be done by passing the component you want to "derive" functionality to a function or by directly wrapping it in a "wrapper" component and accessing the "wrapped" component(s) in the `props.children` property.

```
const componentWithDropTargetCapabilities = addDragAndDrop(MyComponent)
```

or

```
<DropTarget>
   <MyComponent />
</DropTarget>
```

Those are called "higher order components" (HOC) :
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html

Take a look ar react-router code for example: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: From the way I read Hoc it will not work with my updated version of my question or am I missing something?

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Is the output of the question snippet ok? Can you articulate the real use case?

Comment: My optimal scenario would be a "mockup" Component with the basic features where I can send data in and then make the component do stuff however I want the ability to modify some of the steps without having to change/add to the "upper" component in those cases I need it to act a bit different

Comment: Those the "mockup" have a fixed layout? and you just make it show different data and do different things on data? If so why not just using a plain React component and pass data and callbacks in props?

Comment: I still need to have access to things like 'componentWillUnmount' aso in the "upper" component

Comment: Just call a function passed in the props in 'componentWillUnmount'